# Why animation play state is always running?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I couldn't get the animation play state to be `paused` with css3 animation even after using `animation-iteration-count` to `1` and `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards`:

```js
var isRunning = window.getComputedStyle(
  document.querySelector('div')
).getPropertyValue('animation-play-state');

setInterval(function(){
  console.log(isRunning);
},1000)
```

```css
@keyframes foo {
 0% { 
   width: 0;
 }
 100% {
  width: 50%;
 }
}

div {
 animation: foo 2s linear 0s 1 normal forwards;
 background-color: #f00;
 height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I should get `animation-play-state` to be `paused` when it finishes the animation.

---

Actually, the following answer that I provided doesn't work for me. In fact, I was working with a pseudo element and pseudo element doesn't accept addEventListener. So, my final solution would be to use this only way.

```
var isRunning = window.getComputedStyle(
      document.querySelector('div'), ':after'
).getPropertyValue('animation-play-state');
```

Sadly, CSS doesn't seem to set play state to paused when animation is finished. To conclude this question has no findings or solution?

Comment: However I couldn't see the console here in my snippet. Can anyone please fix the snippet to show the console. Thanks.

Comment: I am able to run it without edit.

Comment: Oh, then it might be not showing in linux chromium browser...

Comment: No problem. :-)

Comment: The console is implemented as a div, so it's being affected by the animation. The solution is to not use generic selectors like div. Give your div an id or something.

Comment: @BoltClock No luck even if I use id.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `animation-play-state` doesn't change once an animation finishes all its iterations.

You'll need to listen for the animationend event and change the value manually:

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('animationend', function() {
  this.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue('animation-play-state'));
});
```

```css
@keyframes foo {
 0% { 
   width: 0;
 }
 100% {
   width: 50%;
 }
}

#foo {
 animation: foo 2s linear 0s 1 normal forwards;
 background-color: #f00;
 height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id=foo></div>
```

... though I don't really see any reason to do so when your `animation-fill-mode` is already set to `forwards`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why css3 keeps animation play state to `running` but go with the `animationend` event:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
x.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
  console.log('paused'); // animation is end
});
```

Here's the reference for animationend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend